# How can I reset LiveData<Boolean> when LiveData<MVoice> is changed in Two way data binding in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

The *EditText* use Two-way data binding and *Button* use One-way data binding in *layout_detail.xml*

I hope that *Button* will be enabled when the `aDetailViewModel.aMVoice.name` is changed.

When the content of EditText is changed,  the value of `aMVoice` in `DetailViewModel` will be changed too, I think I can reset the value of `isChanged`, but I don't know how to do? Could you tell me?

**layout_detail.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="aDetailViewModel"
            type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.viewcontrol.DetailViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eTName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@={aDetailViewModel.aMVoice.name}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{aDetailViewModel.isChanged}"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

**Code**

```
class DetailViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository, private val voiceId:Int) : ViewModel() {

   val aMVoice=mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)     //I hope to reset isChanged when aMVoice is changed

   val isChanged: LiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)    
}
  

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    fun getVoiceById(id:Int)=mDBVoiceDao.getVoiceById(id)
}

@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{      
   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table where id=:id")
   fun getVoiceById(id:Int):LiveData<MVoice>
}

@Entity(tableName = "voice_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class MVoice(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
    var name:          String = "",
    var path:          String = "",  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to find out value changes over multiple attributes, we should separate each one in a specific `LiveData` via `map` transformations. These new `LiveData`s play the role of two-way binding.

Finally, to integrate the changes, the best way is to use a `MediatorLiveData` to be triggered by each change and then check the values. So, it's enough to check equality of the initial value from `DB` with the received values from the views.

```
class DetailViewModel(...) {

    private val aMVoice = mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)

    val voiceName = aMVoice.map { it.name } as MutableLiveData<String>
    val voicePath = aMVoice.map { it.path } as MutableLiveData<String>
    // ... (similar for more attributes)

    val isChanged = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
        addSource(voiceName) { postValue(currentMVoice != aMVoice.value) }
        addSource(voicePath) { postValue(currentMVoice != aMVoice.value) }
        // ... (similar for more attributes)
    }

    // it collects current values delivered from views as a `MVoice` object.
    private val currentMVoice: MVoice?
        get() = aMVoice.value?.copy(
            name = voiceName.value ?: "",
            path = voicePath.value ?: "",
            // ... (similar for more attributes)
        )
}
```

Then use `voiceName`, `voicePath`, *etc* in the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eTName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@={aDetailViewModel.voiceName}" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eTPath"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@={aDetailViewModel.voicePath}" />

// ...
```

To use the `map` transformation don't forget to add `lifecycle-livedata-ktx` dependency in `build.gradle` if you didn't before.

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code doesn't work. `val aMVoice = mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId).map { isChanged.postValue(true); it }` will not be launched when the content of `aMVoice` is changed

Comment: Thanks! but I think maybe there are other better ways.  You know I have to check all fields to define if it's changed, it's a complex work if MVoice incude name, path, date, description, isFavorited, etc.

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated again to fit the requirement of checking more attributes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
class DetailViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository, private val voiceId: Int) :
    ViewModel() {

    val aMVoice =
        mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)     //I hope to reset isChanged when aMVoice is changed

    val isChanged: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)

    fun listenChanges(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        aMVoice.observe(owner) {
            isChanged.value?.apply {
                isChanged.value = !this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call listener from where you have you [lifecycle owner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner) - for example from Fragment

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.listenChanges(viewLifecycleOwner)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think your code can run, I can't understand what `isChanged.value = !this` mean

Comment: Try it - it may need some customisation. If you don't understand this part of code this means you don't really know Kotlin and its [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html). Also you may need to use isChanged.postValue(!this) depending on your current execution thread.